# How to read number as a String type and return an output in the equivalent Integer type

Tags: java

**Input is a user string such as --> "ONE" and the output should be '1'
             or,"NINE" output = '9'**

```
   public int check(String s)
   {
    int a=0;
    switch(s)
    {
        case "ZERO": a= 0;
        break;
        case "ONE": a=  1;
        break;
        case "TWO": a= 2;
        break;
        case "THREE": a= 3;
        break;
        case "FOUR": a= 4;
        break;
        case "FIVE": a= 5;
        break;
        case "SIX": a= 6;
        break;
        case "SEVEN": a= 7;
        break;
        case "EIGHT": a= 8;
        break;
        case "NINE": a= 9;
    }
    return a;
}
```

main method

```
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
{
    int k=0,i;
    String wrd="";
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s = br.readLine();
    String str="ONE,ZERO,TWO,THREE,FOUR,FIVE,SIX,SEVEN,EIGHT,NINE,";
    int l = s.length();
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        while(str.charAt(k)!=s.charAt(i))k++;
        if(str.charAt(k)==s.charAt(i))
        {
            while(!(str.charAt(k)==',') && (s.charAt(i)==(str.charAt(k))))
            {
                wrd=wrd+s.charAt(i++);
                k++;
            }
        }
        else
        while(str.charAt(k)!=s.charAt(i))k++;
    }
    System.out.println(wrd);
    Friend obj = new Friend();
    int a = obj.check(wrd);
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

*the code i've written above converts the all other inputs to integer except for "FIVE" "SEVEN" "EIGHT" "NINE" for these inputs the output is '0'*

**THERE MAY BE SOME OTHER EASY WAY TO CONVERT I/P STRING TO INTEGER BUT
I NEED TO HAVE THIS METHOD FOR SOME OTHER PURPOSES.**

Comment: Why not use String.split to turn "FIVE,SEVEN,EIGHT,NINE" into an array and then convert each word individually?  It seems like main(), not check(), is the problem here.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor the program takes single input in form of a string eg:"ONE" and will return "1" or "NINE" and will return "9", the code i've written works fine for all other numbers except "FIVE" "SEVEN' 'EIGHT"  and "NINE" for these it returns 0 instead of 5 7 8 and 9

Comment: So if the string is passed as a command line argument (sorry I thought str was the argument, and didn't notice that s and str were two different variables), why not just call `check(args[0])`? Isn't that all you need to do?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use enum like this:

```
public enum MyNumber {

    ONE(1),
    TWO(2),
    THREE(3);

    private final int value;

    MyNumber(int value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    int getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

and use it...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //test
    System.out.println(MyNumber.ONE.getValue());
    System.out.println(MyNumber.valueOf("ONE"));
}
```

Please, notice that if you write

```
System.out.println(MyNumber.valueOf("ONES"));
```

you will get the run time exception. So, you'll have to check the strings **before** passing the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of the str variable? A simple way to achieve what you want can be:

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
 String s = br.readLine();
 System.out.println(s);
 Friend friend = new Friend();
 int a = friend.check(s);
 System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: yes thats true but i have to modify the code later to read jumbled string, i needed to know the code i am using will work or not

Answer (score 0):

If performance is not an issue, use a `Map<String, Integer>`

i.E.

```
private static Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

static {
    map.put("zero", 0);
    //do this for 1..9 here too
}

public static int check(String string) {
    Integer number = map.get(string.toLowerCase());
    return number == null ? -1 : number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are not using .split()? If it is allowed, you can try:

```
Friend friend = new Friend();
String[] numbers = str.split(",");
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    if(s.equals(numbers[i]){      //You could also do s.toUpperCase().equals(numbers[i])
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(friend.check(s));
        break;
    }
}
```

However, if you cannot use .split(), the problem with your solution is multiple while loops nested inside for loops. You can solve this by using if statement instead. Try this:

```
 for(i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        while(str.charAt(k)!=s.charAt(i)){
        k++;
        }
        if((str.charAt(k) != ',') && (s.charAt(i)==(str.charAt(k))))
        {
            wrd=wrd+s.charAt(i);      //You don't need to use while since 
            k++;                      //you are already in for loop. So i++ is already done
        }
    }
```

Also it will be optimal to use try catch blocks or exceptions if you do not want to run into errors.